# Flutter webview with javascript enable

Tags: javascript, webview, flutter

Flutter plugin [webview](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) and use javascript to print the web page, but only the javascript is not working in webview. Please kindly help to solve this issue.

Flutter code:

```
Future<Null> _launchInWebViewWithJavaScript(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(
        url,
        forceSafariVC: true,
        forceWebView: false,
        enableJavaScript: true,
      );
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

Webpage code (php, javascript and html):

```
<?php
    $qrString = $_GET['qrString'];
    $tableNumber = $_GET['tableNumber'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>receipt</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../paper.css">
  <style>
    @page { size: 75mm 100mm } /* output size */
    body.receipt .sheet { width: 58mm; height: 100mm } /* sheet size */
    @media print { body.receipt { width: 58mm } } /* fix for Chrome */
  </style>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body class="receipt">
  <section class="sheet padding-10mm">
        <?php echo '<h1>檯號: '.$tableNumber. '</h1><br>' ?>


      <img id='barcode' 
            src=<?php echo 'https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=' .$qrString. '&amp;size=300x300' ?>
            alt="" 
            title="HELLO" 
            width="300" 
            height="300" />
  </section>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.print();
</script>
</html>
```

The webpage is working fine with browser Chrome and Safari.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use **flutter_webview_plugin:**
Following will be route code

```
routes: {
"/webview": (_) => WebviewScaffold(
url: url,
appBar: AppBar(
title: Text("Webview"),
),
withJavascript: true,
withLocalStorage: true,
withZoom: true,
)
},
```

Comment: it is same, javascript is not working when we go to the webpage. It suppose to start printing preview, but it didn't show printing preview.

Comment: Yes. This plugin gives an error which says "Browser not supported". Means ES6 is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

May be too late to answer, but for my case it solved by upgrading webview from [playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview&hl=en_IN&gl=US).
Earlier before this my webview was complaining about ES^ syntaxes like arrow function and spread operator. Aftre this it works all fine!